# How much to remove when trimming dead leaves on a squash plant?

Tags: vegetables, leaves, plant-care, squash

I am specifically asking this regarding a squash plant, but general advice would be useful. If I have dead leaves, which I assume I should remove, should I remove the whole stem that it is growing from, or just the leaf? The stem looks perfectly healthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove dead parts is the general rule, provided the stem or branch is healthy.